# V3 Client Auth breaks systemctl default service

Tags: configuration

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111276/not-able-to-create-private-v3-onion-service/111603#111603

This is related to the above post. Running tor with `-f /etc/tor/torrc` works fine, but it breaks the systemctl service when ClientOnionAuthDir is added to

edit: I have tried changing the ownership of the file. I also tried changing `user` and other things in the launch options of `/lib/systemd/system/tor@*`. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in bitcoin thread.

It was a permissions problem for the service. The folder and file needed to be authored by `-u debian-tor` otherwise it would not work.

The commands i used:

`sudo -u debian-tor mkdir /var/lib/tor/onion-auth; sudo vim /var/lib/tor/onion-auth/x1.auth_private`